# UV Mapping Mirrored Vertices

Tags: modeling, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, mirror

I'm not sure what is going on here, but it looks like the UV Smart Project assigned two islands to the same faces. This might be because I mirrored the vertices while modelling. How do I fix this? You can see in the UV Mapping, there are two islands with the same stroke that I applied from the 3D Workspace... I cannot draw on the other half of the tail feather, which is the part where I mirrored the vertices while modelling. How do I fix this so the second island is on the mirrored vertices half?

[image: screenshot of texture painting on UV Map and 3d Workspace]

Comment: In that case you need to unwrap again, at least move the face where you don't want the painting to happen?

Comment: Select All in Edit mode, M > Merge by distance, then unwrap again?